# ifconfig no inet no inet6 after newly install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 myself. After reboot

the network (wifi) doesn't work anymore, I do not have cable, so haven't tried

```
ifconfig

the eth0 doesn't have inet or inet6 item
```

and

```
lspci -knn! grep Net -A2

03:00.0 Network controller (0280): Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (14e4:4365) (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device (17aa:0611)
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

quite emergency. How could I deal with it ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Do you have a wired internet access?

Comment: @Pilot6 no, but I can download package from another computer and install I think

Comment: You need to install the driver. See the above link.

Comment: If it does not work then post your laptop model name and output of `rfkill list`. On some Lenovo models it may be blocked.

Comment: @Pilot6 it works. Thanks a lot. That saved my life